# FCM in background in swift

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, background, firebase-cloud-messaging

My question is basically if I can detect when a push notification arrives when the app is in the background, the notification itself .. if it arrives, it shows me, but I need to detect the notification data when it arrives in the background without having to touch the notification..

Answer (score 0):

You can't if it's a push with a message payload. They're always shown to the user, and you don't get any callbacks unless the user taps it, or the app was in the foreground when it was received.

I would approach this by sending a silent notification, and then when the app receives it, scheduling a local notification to show the message to the user.

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/usernotifications/setting_up_a_remote_notification_server/pushing_background_updates_to_your_app

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/usernotifications/scheduling_a_notification_locally_from_your_app